# get_categories returns top-level categories instead of child categories

Tags: categories

I've made a basic subcategory nav menu using the code below.

The problem is on *one* category (with NO children), it returns the Top Level categories as children, e.g.: News, Uncategorized, etc. (I've tried assigning a child category and it actually disappears from the menu instead of fixing things)

What could be causing this?

```
function display_category_breadcrumbs () {
    $current_cat_id = get_cat_id( single_cat_title("",false) );    
    $parent_cats = get_categories('parent='.$current_cat_id);  

    ?> <ul id="cat-breadcrumb"> <?php
    foreach ($parent_cats as $sub_category ) {
        echo '<li><a href="'. esc_url( get_category_link( $sub_category->term_id) ) . '">' . esc_html( $sub_category->cat_name) . '</a></li>';
    }
    ?> </ul> <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're seeing is the expected behavior when `parent` is set to `0` which is what `get_cat_id()` returns if it fails to find a category ID for the `$cat_name` argument. You can quickly test this by putting `var_dump($current_cat_id);` anytime after you set it to see if this guess is right. If so, you'll need to figure out why you're not getting a `$current_cat_id`.

The way you're doing it right now strikes me as fairly error-prone though it's hard to know without more context. I'd look to get the ID directly from a `get_the_terms()` if you're on single posts or maybe with `get_query_var()` if on a term archive page.

*Tangentially, your code shouldn't be working at all if what you pasted is unedited since your `if` statement has no test to perform.*

Comment: Thanks, mrwweb. Could you tell me more about what you mean by error-prone? 

The error only shows up in production (so var_dump is a last resort ), and on staging the exact same category doesn't display the same error.

Deleted the "if", thanks for the heads up ( copied a version I had started editing: the if is not the issue. ) :)

Comment: If there's a way to directly get the ID rather than transform the term, that's going to work more often, I suspect. Re: production, you can always `var_dump` into an html comment: `<!-- <?php var_dump( $current_cat_id ); ?> -->`